# Excel - get (extract) all names of the cities from the range

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, address

I have situations such as this:

[image]

where between the bunch of addresses reaching the 3000th row I have the name of the town from time to time.
In order to avoid scrolling thru this whole list and rewriting them, I think, that maybe Excel has some formula for extraction just these particular strings and placing them in a separate cell or list of cells.
Is it possible?

Comment: You could change the layout of the pivot table so it is no longer in "compact" mode, then all the towns would be in one column, albeit with lots of spaces between them, which would be trivial to remove by simply sorting the data once you have pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can use the Collapse all data button for Pivot Tables

https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/collapse-rows-and-columns/how-to-collapse-rows-and-columns-in-excel

Click on any expandable data (pivot table) and select from the **Main bar -> Data -> Outline -> Hide Detail option**
[image]

all pivot tables will be collapsed giving you the opportunity for copying the list of cities.